# Почему выходит мусор?

Tags: c++

Вводить с клавиатуры целые числа. Условие окончания ввода  число 0. Найти среди
этих чисел наименьшее (0 не считать наименьшим).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ukr");
    const int x = 10;
    int i = 0;
    int Arr[x];
    for (i; i < x; i++)
    {
        cin >> Arr[i];
        if (Arr[i] == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    int min = Arr[0];
    for (i = 1; i < x; i++)
    {
        if (Arr[i] < min)
        {
            min = Arr[i];
        }
    }
    cout << min << " наименьшее число в массиве" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Потому что вы можете остановить ввод раньше, чем 10 чисел, а минимум ищете по всем 10...

Comment: В чем смысл `for (i;...`? Не первый раз вижу эту манеру.

Answer (score 2):

Поскольку массив int Arr[x] вы не инициализируете, в нем изначально хранится мусор. Далее вы в массив записываете значения, но, допустим, 5 записали и последующим 0-ём ввод закончился. Соответственно, у вас первые 5 элементов ok, а в остальных так и остаётся мусор. Далее вы ищите минимум по всем элементам массива из введенных 5-ти элементов и мусора в остальных элементах и где-то среди мусора находится это наименьшее число, которое вам выводится.